# New to LINQ: Is this the right place to use LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, xna

First off, I'm new to LINQ, so I don't really know the ins and outs of it. I'm attempting to use it in some code at the minute, and according to my diagnostics it appears to be about as fast as using a for loop in the same way. However, I'm not sure how well this would scale as the lists which I am working with could increase quite dramatically.

I'm using LINQ as part of a collision detection function (which is still in the works) and I'm using it to cull the list to only the ones that are relevant for the checks.

Here is the LINQ version:

```
partial class Actor {
    public virtual bool checkActorsForCollision(Vector2 toCheck) {
        Vector2 floored=new Vector2((int)toCheck.X, (int)toCheck.Y);

        if(!causingCollision) // skip if this actor doesn't collide
            return false;

        foreach(
            Actor actor in
            from a in GamePlay.actors
            where a.causingCollision==true&&a.isAlive
            select a
            )
            if( // ignore offscreen collisions, we don't care about them
                (actor.location.X>GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.X)
                &&
                (actor.location.Y>GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.Y)
                &&
                (actor.location.X<GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.X)
                &&
                (actor.location.Y<GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.Y)
                )
                if(actor!=this) { // ignore collisions with self
                    Vector2 actorfloor=new Vector2((int)actor.location.X, (int)actor.location.Y);

                    if((floored.X==actorfloor.X)&&(floored.Y==actorfloor.Y))
                        return true;
                }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my previous method:

```
partial class Actor {
    public virtual bool checkActorsForCollision(Vector2 toCheck) {
        Vector2 floored=new Vector2((int)toCheck.X, (int)toCheck.Y);

        if(!causingCollision) // skip if this actor doesn't collide
            return false;

        for(int i=0; i<GamePlay.actors.Count; i++)
            if( // ignore offscreen collisions, we don't care about them
                (GamePlay.actors[i].location.X>GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.X)
                &&
                (GamePlay.actors[i].location.Y>GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.Y)
                &&
                (GamePlay.actors[i].location.X<GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.X)
                &&
                (GamePlay.actors[i].location.Y<GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.Y)
                )
                if( // ignore collisions with self
                    (GamePlay.actors[i].isAlive)
                    &&
                    (GamePlay.actors[i]!=this)
                    &&
                    (GamePlay.actors[i].causingCollision)
                    ) {
                    Vector2 actorfloor=
                        new Vector2(
                            (int)GamePlay.actors[i].location.X,
                            (int)GamePlay.actors[i].location.Y
                            );

                    if((floored.X==actorfloor.X)&&(floored.Y==actorfloor.Y))
                        return true;
                }

        return false;
    }
}
```

At the minute, either run in almost no time (but run numerous times a second), but as the project builds and gets more intricate, this will be dealing with far more objects at once and the code to check for collisions will be more detailed.

Comment: Your code is totally correct. LINQ is quite performant, extremely performant in some cases, less in some others. The best thing you can do is to try and compare.

Comment: "However, I'm not sure how well this would scale as the lists which I am working with could increase quite dramatically." Then you should measure that. You should be able to easily create some big testing data and run your code on that.

Comment: If you need better performance, you should replace your O(n^2) collision detection with an algorithm that scales better.

Comment: It really is a stretch to call LINQ performant in a game development setting. As soon as you become CPU- or GC-bound, this will almost certainly be a hot-spot that you'll have to revert to a regular loop. It's just a question of whether you will become CPU- or GC-bound in the first place. For a uncomplicated game on a good Windows box at 60FPS: unlikely. On the Xbox 360: the GC is going to *hate* you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good; I'm not a big fan of changing working code, but if you did want to rewrite it to be easier to read, here's what I would do:

First, abstract away the predicate "is off the screen". Perhaps make it a method of GamePlay. This business of checking every time whether the coordinates are in the bounds is (1) an implementation detail, and (2) making your code hard to read. It is possible that in the future you will have some more sophisticated mechanism for deciding whether an object is on the screen or not.

Second, abstract away the vector flooring operation. Perhaps make it a method of Vector. Note that this method should return a new vector, not mutate the existing vector.

Third, make an equality operator on vectors.

Fourth, name the method better. A predicate should have the form "IsFoo" or "HasFoo". You've phrased it as a command, not as a question.

Fifth, you don't need a loop at all.

Sixth, it is strange to say `somebool == true`.  Just say `somebool`. The former means "if it is true that this bool is true", which is needlessly complicated.

Let's see how this shakes out:

```
public virtual bool HasCollisionWithAnyActor(Vector2 toCheck)
{
    // "Easy out": if this actor does not cause collisions then
    // we know that it is not colliding with any actor.
    if (!causingCollision)
      return false;

    Vector2 floored = toCheck.Floor();

    var collidingActors = 
      from actor in GamePlay.actors
      where actor != this
      where actor.causingCollision
      where actor.isAlive
      where GamePlay.IsOnScreen(actor.location)
      where actor.location.Floor() == floored
      select actor;

    return collidingActors.Any();
}
```

Look at how much easier that reads than your version of the method! None of this messing around with X and Y coordinates. **Make helper methods do all that scutwork.** The code now clearly expresses the semantics: tell me whether there are any collisions with other living, collision-causing actors on the screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the list of tips, they all make great sense. The Vector class is coming from XNA itself so I wasn't sure about making any changes to this, but seeing what that would give me, I might well do so. For the sixth one, I find that leaving the whole thing "== true" or "== false" helps in some cases for readability, I believe they compile to the same in the end anyway, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Lyise: If you don't have access to the vector class, you can always write extension methods.

Comment: @Lyise: Consider this answer as your solution, it is what Linq for.

Comment: @Eric I don't believe I have access to the Vector class itself (I can't check at the minute to make sure unfortunately), but I'm going to take the extension route if not. Thanks a lot for all of the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here LINQ version is faster than the previous one because you have forgotten to create a local variable to store the `GamePlay.actors[i]`. Then, access to the `actors` array if done a lot of times in the `for` loop.

```
public virtual bool checkActorsForCollision(Vector2 toCheck)
{
    Vector2 floored = new Vector2((int) toCheck.X, (int) toCheck.Y);

    if (!causingCollision) // skip if this actor doesn't collide
    return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < GamePlay.actors.Count; i++)
    {
        Actor actor = GamePlay.actors[i];
        // ignore offscreen collisions, we don't care about them
        if ((actor.location.X > GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.X) &&
            (actor.location.Y > GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.Y) &&
            (actor.location.X < GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.X) &&
            (actor.location.Y < GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.Y))
        {

            if ((actor.isAlive) && (actor != this) &&
                (actor.causingCollision)) // ignore collisions with self
            {
                Vector2 actorfloor =
                  new Vector2((int) actor.location.X,
                              (int) actor.location.Y);
                if ((floored.X == actorfloor.X) &&
                    (floored.Y == actorfloor.Y))
                  return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, LINQ as very good performancies in general. But there are some cases where it's better to use the classical `for` version. You have to find the right balance between the lisibility of your code and the performances (by comparing LINQ version and `for` version). For my part, I use and abuse of LINQ because I really like its syntax and its lisibility.

Here is a complete LINQ version:

```
return (from actor in GamePlay.actors
        where actor.causingCollision && a.isAlive
        where actor != this
        where (actor.location.X > GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.X) &&
              (actor.location.Y > GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.Y) &&
              (actor.location.X < GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.X) &&
              (actor.location.Y < GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.Y)
        select new Vector2((int)actor.location.X,
                           (int)actor.location.Y)).Any(actorfloor => (floored.X == actorfloor.X) &&
                                                                     (floored.Y == actorfloor.Y));
```

Comment: Thanks for all of this. I hadn't realise that referencing GamePlay.actors[i] would be slower than creating a local copy. Now that I can see from what you've said (and others), I think I'll move more of that function into a LINQ version as that looks a lot more readable.

Comment: Lots of answers here are focusing on LINQ's performance in terms of _raw speed_, but I don't think that's really what you need to be concerned about here.  The real problem with using LINQ in an XNA game--and especially in a collision detection function that will likely be called multiple times per frame--is its tendency to throw garbage all over the managed heap, often invisibly.

Comment: @ColeCampbell This is why all answers suggest to measure performances. But, that's right the overhead of using LINQ is visible only in few situations.

Comment: Consider using a query continuation. Instead of "from a in (from b in c select d) where e select f" say "from b in c select d into a ..." . Its easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with using LINQ here. If you want to really know if you are increasing the performance you should do some meassuring with Diagnostics.StopWatch

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks.aspx

Also, you can use even more LINQ like this to make the function a bit more compact.

```
return (from actor in (from a in GamePlay.actors
                                   where a.CausingCollision == true && a.IsAlive
                                   select a)
                    where (actor.location.X > GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.X) && (actor.location.Y > GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.Y) && (actor.location.X < GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.X) && (actor.location.Y < GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.Y)
                    where actor != this
                    select new Vector2((int) actor.location.X, (int) actor.location.Y)).Any(actorfloor => (floored.X == actorfloor.X) && (floored.Y == actorfloor.Y));
```

Comment: From the numbers that I got using StopWatch, the two seemed pretty similar, which the size of the list which I'm currently using which is why I thought it would be worth asking here as well, before I run into a problem further down the line. Thanks a lot for the LINQ version of the rest, I think that will be my next step now that it sounds like LINQ would be the better route to take.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the Question, but in general I think it's always a better solution to use LINQ instead of creating additional loops and if/else calls.

FYI:
you can also use the LINQ-Methodes instead of the key-words, like:

```
foreach(Actor actor in from a in GamePlay.actors
                           where a.causingCollision == true 
                           && a.isAlive
                           select a)
{
  //...
}
```

is the same as:

```
foreach(Actor actor in GamePlay.actors.Where( a => a.causingCollision == true && a.isAlive))
{
  //...
}
```

the return in both cases is a filtered IEnumerable. My personal opinion is that the methodes are easier to read and understand. In the Where(...) you can put a complete lambda-expression to completly select only the Actors you want.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I wasn't aware that I would be able to do this as well. I had read about using that form but was unsure about which would be better when (if there is a difference).

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is quite optimised, and its output is the same as manually writing your fors.
By the way, extension methods are much more readable. Your example will look like this:

```
public virtual bool checkActorsForCollision(Vector2 toCheck)
{
    Vector2 floored = new Vector2((int)toCheck.X, (int)toCheck.Y);

    // skip if this actor doesn't collide
    if (!causingCollision)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return GamePlay.actors.Where( actor =>    
            (actor.causingCollision == true) 
            && actor.isAlive
            // ignore offscreen collisions, we don't care about them
            && (actor.location.X > GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.X) 
            && (actor.location.Y > GamePlay.onScreenMinimum.Y)          
            && (actor.location.X < GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.X) 
            && (actor.location.Y < GamePlay.onScreenMaximum.Y)
            // ignore collisions with self
            && (actor != this) )
        .Select( actor => new Vector2((int)actor.location.X, (int)actor.location.Y) )
        .Any( actorFloor => 
            (floored.X == actorfloor.X) 
            && (floored.Y == actorfloor.Y));
}
```

There's no reason not to use LINQ for "performance reasons" if you haven't profiled your application.